# SATA Hard drive not detecting

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a dead laptop, Trying to recover data from the Hard drive (Sata2)

1. I tried putting the HD in one similar laptop , it's not recognized
2. I got USB-SATA Adapter and plugged the HD ,  and still the HD is not recognized

can you tell me is there any other possible way to get my data back ?

Comment: Do you get any kind of error messages when you try and access the drive?

Comment: No, .. No errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there ANY signs of life from the drive?   Does it spin up, or make any clicking noises?  Have you tried plugging it in directly to a SATA port on a desktop?

I once had a drive that exhibited similar problems, but it was definitely powering up (and clicking).  I put it in the freezer overnight and the next morning got it running long enough to get all my data off.

Comment: it wont spin, i am guessing the control board is dead

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tried putting your HDD onto another laptop and it still does not work and you've added a USB-SATA cable extender and it is still not working it seems like your disk has failed.

You can Google hard disk recovery of a failed drive. Beware though this is a service and can cost thousands to get your data back.